# Image Segmentation Using Prior Shape Information Matlab

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, classification, shapes, image-segmentation

I have a series of medical images from which I am attempting to segment out and analyze the ECG tracings in Matlab (the green, spiking line in the image below):

[image]

I have so far been successful in doing this on a small set of images using color thresholding and region properties. My problem is that almost all aspects of this feature of interest can change depending on the manufacturer of the machine used to produce the images and the behavior of the user operating it (over which I have 0 control).

Potentially differing attributes include line position in the image (which can change to be almost anywhere in the image), amplitude, frequency, and even color (which can be changed to match the color of the large white surface under the line in the above image). This makes it extremely difficult to create a robust segmentation solution for all images relying only on "simple" methods (color segmentation, region properties, edge detection etc).

Would it be straight forward to train a classifier to identify the general shape of this line and segment it out? Alternatively, is there another way to search and segment an image using prior shape information?

Comment: Not sure, but that's pretty bradycardic, and also looks like long Q-T syndrome, so if that's yours I'd get regular cardiac check ups. For the sake of your analysis perhaps it'd be better starting with a healthy ECG, as they are definitely the most common. Also if you're wanting it be be diagnostic, then you can't rely on features always being there (defined QRS complex, flat P-Q interval, flat S-T interval). This is me with my medical hat on, not my MATLAB hat, though.

Comment: Thankfully that is not me XD. We're doing a study on a population with AS, and I only want to use the ECG for gating the echo at this stage

Answer (score 0):

If you are currently applying an arbitrary threshold, you can look at various technique for dynamic thresholding ([here a technique that applies the concept on edge detection](http://www.iaeng.org/publication/WCE2008/WCE2008_pp694-699.pdf)).

What you could also try is to threshold on a different representation of the image, such as [HSL and HSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) (as I am assuming you are thresholding on the RGB values)

Comment: Currently I am performing my thresholding in the Lab color space. I will have to look into this dynamic thresholding. I question how well this will work though if the line color is changed such that it resembles the bulk white color, and is shifted on top of that color mass (which I have seen happen in some images).

Answer (score 0):

You may use a classifier and active contour model to segment the desired region. An example can be found here: http://pratondo.staff.telkomuniversity.ac.id/2016/01/14/robust-edge-stop-functions-for-edge-based-active-contour-models-in-medical-image-segmentation/